# Name for the point at which two sub-functions belonging to a piecewise function meet

Tags: terminology, piecewise-continuity

Consider the following piecewise function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  -x, & \mbox{if } x \leq 0 \\
  x,  & \mbox{if } x \ge 0 
\end{cases}$$

I would like a technical term to refer to the point $x = 0$ which is the point at which the domains of the sub-functions intersect. For this specific example I could refer to it as the point at which the derivative $f'(x)$ is discontinuous however piecewise functions need not be discontinuous and so does a general term for this point exist? If not could you make a sensible recommendation on how to refer to it?

Comment: A bending point?